# How to share data between API route and getServerSideProps?

Tags: node.js, next.js, shared-memory

Suppose need to fetch non-client specific data `x` from an external API. To reduce loading time, I want to fetch `x` once, cache it and only fetch it again when:

1. a client request requires `x` and
2. my cached data of `x` is older than `ttl` seconds.

How do I achieve this in a way I can access the cached data of `x` from both an API route as well as `getServerSideProps`?

##### My approaches

###### `x` as a static class property

I created a class `Provider` with a static method `getX` that will

- fetch `x` and save it as `Provider.x` if `Provider.x` is undefined or the previous fetch is longer than `ttl` seconds old and then
- return `Provider.x`.

This does not work, since `Provider.x` in `getServerSideProps` and `Provider.x` in the API route do not point to the same object in memory. I suppose this is due to them running in individual workers.

###### Saving `x` to a file

Similar to the first approach, except saving `x` to a local file rather than a static property. This does work, but is very slow as it has to read and write on the hard disk instead of in memory.

Comment: `getServerSideProps` will trigger every time the user access page. You can't access the cache from `getServerSideProps`. In this case, you need to add "middleware" which will save some cached info. Your approach is good enough, but why do you need to use cached data?

Comment: Do you _have to_ cache the data on the server? Could you not use a `Cache-Control` header, and cache it on the browser?

Comment: I am looking to cache the data on the server since the external API call to retrieve `x` returns a combination of data that the client needs and data that the client shouldn't have access to. Therefore, if I cache only the client data on client-side, the server will still have to request `x` again to retrieve the remaining data. @juliomalves

Comment: @illiachill Yes, adding middleware solves the problem but all approaches to middleware that I've come across thus far seem very bloated and too big for my requirements. That's why I was wondering if there wasn't some simple way of keeping a small amount of shared memory; like saving the file except in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Node.js [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global) object to share data between API routes and `getServerSideProps`.

For instance, you could set the data in the `getServerSideProps` function.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    // Set data in `global` object
    global._SOME_DATA_ = { data: { hello: 'world' }, ttl: '3600' }
    // ...
}
```

Then retrieve that same data at a later point in the API route.

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
    console.log(global._SOME_DATA_) // Logs: `{ data: { hello: 'world' }, ttl: '3600' }`
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I tried and get the same issue as @jannis. As @jannis said "Provider.x in getServerSideProps and Provider.x in the API route do not point to the same object in memory", which I also think is due to the lambda context of routes and api are different. That also applies to `global`